# A better way to add default color the Text component?

Tags: react-native

Does anyone know a good way to change the default text color of the Text component?

Here is my attempt by wrapping it in a MyText component.

```
import styles from 'somewhere';  // import default color

function MyText(props) {
  return (
    <Text
      style={[styles.default, props.style]}
      allowFontScaling={props.allowFontScaling}
      numberOfLines={props.numberOfLines}
      onLayout={props.onLayout}
      onLongPress={props.onLongPress}
      onPress={props.onPress}
      suppressHighlighting={props.suppressHighlighting}
      testID={props.testID}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Text>
  );
}

MyText.propTypes = {
  allowFontScaling: PropTypes.bool,
  children: PropTypes.any,
  numberOfLines: PropTypes.number,
  onLayout: PropTypes.func,
  onLongPress: PropTypes.func,
  onPress: PropTypes.func,
  style: PropTypes.object,
  suppressHighlighting: PropTypes.bool,
  testID: PropTypes.string,
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved

```
function MyText({
  children,
  style,
  ...props
}) {
  return (
    <Text
      {...props}
      style={[styles.default, style]}
    >
      {children}
    </Text>
  );
}
```

Comment: Couldn't `children` be left out of the destructuring and just be passed as part of `...props`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this more cleanly and simply with Glamorous Native:

```
import glamorous from "glamorous-native";

const MyText = glamorous.text({ ...styles });

<MyText>
  ...
</MyText
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.defaultProps` props like this, I've put mine on the my app.js root, since the default color of all of my component text is white. You can also do this on TextInput component. Tested on RN-0.63

```js
    import { Text, TextInput } from 'react-native'
    
    
    export default MyApp() {

     Text.defaultProps.style = {color: 'white'}
     TextInput.defaultProps.style = {color: 'blue'}

     return (
        <Text>My color is White</Text>
        <Text>My color is White too</Text>
        <TextInput>My color is Blue</TextInput>
     )
    
    }
```